# Why does form.is_valid return false. Please advice

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, http-post

I have a project where one books a room online then is directed to the checkout page where you input a phone which is required in the backend. Code is as below:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class AvailabilityForm(forms.Form):

    check_in = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'], required=True)
    check_out = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'], required=True)


class PhoneNoForm(forms.Form):

    phone_no = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

views.py

```
class RoomDetailView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)

        got_category = get_room_category(category)

        print(category)
        print(got_category)
    
        form = AvailabilityForm()

        if got_category is not None:
        
            context = {
                'category':got_category,
                'form':form
            }

            return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Category Nyet!")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
        form = AvailabilityForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
    
            available_rooms = get_available_rooms(category, data['check_in'], data['check_out'] )

            if available_rooms is not None:

                room = available_rooms[0]

                context = {
                    'room':room
                }
        
                return render(request, 'booking/checkout.html', context)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("We're out of those rooms" )
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form invlid')

class CheckoutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'booking/checkout.html'

    def get_phone(request):
        if request.POST:
            phone_no = request.POST.get('PhoneNo', None)
            print(phone_no)

            cl = MpesaClient()
            # Use a Safaricom phone number that you have access to, for you to be able to view the prompt
            phone_number = phone_no
            amount = 1
            account_reference = 'reference'
            transaction_desc = 'Description' 
            callback_url = 'https://darajambili.herokuapp.com/express-payment'

          # callback_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('booking:mpesa_stk_push_callback'))
            response = cl.stk_push(phone_number, amount, account_reference, transaction_desc, callback_url)

            return HttpResponse(response.text)
        
        else:
            return HttpResponse('This is else')
```

checkout.html

```
    <div>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="Input No.">Input Phone No. :</label>
        <input type="number" name="id_PhoneNo" id="PhoneNo">
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed">
      </form>
    </div>
```

detail.html

```
<form id="booking-form" action="" method="POST">

  {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="input-div">
      <label for="id_check_in">Check In : </label>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="id_check_in" name="check_in">
    </div>

    <div class="input-div">
      <label for="id_check_out">Check Out : </label>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="id_check_out" name="check_out">
    </div>

    <div class="input-div">
      <button type="submit">Book the Room</button>
    </div>

  </form>
```

`form.is_valid` returns False. I have tried using GET method but i need the phone number for more processing hence my insistence on using POST. If possible, help me fast. Where is the problem? Sorry if it's too much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the errors to the HTML pages to see why the error is occurring. So, if the form is not valid, send that to HTML page by:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
    form = AvailabilityForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
        got_category = get_room_category(category)

        context = {
            'category':got_category,
            'form':form
        }

        return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

And render the errors like this(as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)):

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

FYI, rather than directly subclassing the `View`, you should use [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView). Here is an example code on how to use:

```
class RoomDetailView(FormView):
    form_class = AvailabilityForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
        got_category = get_room_category(category)
        if got_category is not None:
            context.update({
                'category':got_category,
            })
            return context
        else:
            raise Http404("Category does not exist")

     def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        available_rooms = get_available_rooms(category, data['check_in'], data['check_out'] )
        if available_rooms is not None:  # this part should be in a separate view
           room = available_rooms[0]
           context = {
               'room':room
           }
           return render(request, 'booking/checkout.html', context)
        else:
           return HttpResponse("We're out of those rooms" )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I followed the steps to render the errors and found i had issues with input formats. Other than that, once i have the phone number entered in checkout.html, on submit i am redirected back to detail.html instead of the response page. What may be the issue?

Comment: You are not handling post method in CheckOutView. That is why it is redirecting to “/“ path probably